# I will be able to start working vs I will be able to join the company

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idiomatic-language

I have to write one of the following phrases into a formal correspondence (job application) in order to ask a confirmation:

> Could you please confirm that I will be able to start working on that date ?

> Could you please confirm that I will be able to join the company on that date ?

Which sounds more natural/appropriate in that context ?

This is the context : 
I would therefore assure you that I accept the terms and I am willing to start on 10 th of June. I just wanted to be sure that I understood it correctly, before booking the flight. Could you please.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences are correct but the underlying message is like you are asking them a confirmation from you if you are okay to start on that date, not a confirmation from the management. It will be redundant since you already have confirmed that you are willing to start on that date.

I think you should reconstruct your message to something like asking for a confirmation if the said date (June 10) is the final date of your first day so you can book your flight.

Comment: Or rephrase it to "Can you please confirm if June 10 is the final date so I will be able to book my flight ahead of time?" or something